# Upload image with codeigniter (IOS image-picker)

Tags: javascript, php, ios, codeigniter

the problem I'm having is with a code I found in this page. I have this form in which I want to take a picture from chrome browser on the ipad. I used the following code:

```
   <script>
      $("#image-picker").change( function (event) {
      var files = event.target.files;
      if (files.length>0) {
        // Do something with files[0]
      }
    });
/script>

<input id="image-picker" type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

What I want to know is how can I store the picture taken from the browser, I'm using codeigniter by the way, any sort of help will be deeply appreciated.

Basically what I need is, take the picture from the browser, save it to a folder within codeigniter and save that location in the database.

Comment: use ajax to post that file to Codeigniter

Comment: Yeah, I read something about it, but I didn't find anything that can take the picture on the explorer and save it